# Filter tree list retaining parent using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model class which looks something like this:

```
public class Employee
{ 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Designation {get;set;}
    public List<Employee> Reportees {get;set;}
}
```

using which I simulated a demo tree list with data:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee
    {
        Id = 1,
        ParentId = 0,
        Name = "A",
        Designation = "CEO",
        Reportees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { Id = 2, ParentId = 1,Name = "B",Designation = "Manager",Reportees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee { Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "D", Designation = "Lead", Reportees = new List<Employee>
                {
                    new Employee { Id = 6, ParentId = 4, Name = "F", Designation = "Developer", Reportees = new List<Employee>() },
                    new Employee { Id = 7, ParentId = 4, Name = "G", Designation = "Developer", Reportees = new List<Employee>() }
                }},
                new Employee { Id = 3, ParentId = 1,Name = "C",Designation = "Manager",Reportees = new List<Employee>
                {
                    new Employee { Id = 5, ParentId = 3, Name = "E", Designation = "Lead", Reportees = new List<Employee>
                    {
                        new Employee { Id = 8, ParentId = 5, Name = "H", Designation = "Developer", Reportees = new List<Employee>() }
                    }}
                }}
            }}
        }
    }
};
```

I need to filter the above list to show even the parent object if the child satisfies the filter condition. Also a catch here is if it is a parent which satisfies the condition and the children do not they are omitted.

Are there any extensions available or can I use LINQ to do this?

To make it more clear this is what is the expected filtered list in case the filter search criteria are the Ids **6 and 7**:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee {Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "A",Designation = "CEO", Reportees = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee {Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "B",Designation = "Manager", Reportees = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee {Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "D", Designation = "Lead", Reportees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee {Id = 6, ParentId = 4, Name = "F", Designation = "Developer", Reportees = new List<Employee>() },
                new Employee {Id = 7, ParentId = 4, Name = "G", Designation = "Developer", Reportees = new List<Employee>() }
            }}
        }}
    }}
};
```

and if the Id to filter is **6**:

```
new List<Employee> employees
{
    new Employee{Id = 1,ParentId = 0,Name = "A",Designation = "CEO",Reportees = new List<Employee>{
      new Employee{Id = 2,ParentId = 1,Name = "B",Designation = "Manager",Reportees = new List<Employee>{
        new Employee{Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "D", Designation = "Lead", Reportees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee{Id = 6, ParentId = 4, Name = "F", Designation = "Developer", Reportees = new List<Employee> () }
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

and if the Id to filter is **2**:

```
new List<Employee> employees
{
    new Employee{Id = 1,ParentId = 0,Name = "A",Designation = "CEO",Reportees = new List<Employee>{
      new Employee{Id = 2,ParentId = 1,Name = "B",Designation = "Manager",Reportees = new List<Employee>()}
    }
};C#
```

Comment: I don't believe, that there are any extensions for that. You can use recursive search for that. And please share the code, which you've tried

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski What I did was to flatten the tree list and filter the resultant list and reform the tree. But don't think it was the most efficient solution though I was able to get what I resultant data filtered

Comment: Please, share your current solution and make your code sample compile, because `new List<Employee> employees` is invalid declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the method that you need:

```
List<Employee> FilterEmployees(List<Employee> source, Func<Employee, bool> predicate) =>
    source
        .Select(e => new { employee = e, reportees = FilterEmployees(e.Reportees, predicate) })
        .Where(x => predicate(x.employee) || x.reportees.Any())
        .Select(x => new Employee
        {
            Id = x.employee.Id,
            ParentId = x.employee.ParentId,
            Name = x.employee.Name,
            Designation = x.employee.Designation,
            Reportees = x.reportees,
        })
        .ToList();
```

The two crucial lines of this method are the first `Select` and the `Where`.

The first `Select` keeps track of the current `employee` and recursively calls `FilterEmployees` to get any `Reportees` that match.

The `Where` decides if we want to keep the current `employee` - the criteria being did the employee meet the predicate or did any of its `Reportees`.

Finally, it just builds the new `Employee` to return.

For `FilterEmployees(employees, e => e.Id == 6 || e.Id == 7)` we get:

[image: 6 & 7]

For `FilterEmployees(employees, e => e.Id == 6)` we get:

[image: 6]

For `FilterEmployees(employees, e => e.Id == 2)` we get:

[image: 2]

Answer (score -1):

I have Two solution for you:

1)Create a function to access employee object from its ID

2)create a childsID property like:

```
new Employee{Id = 1,ParentId = 0, childsID=new list<int>(){2,4,6,7}, ...}
```

after both you can easily do the job with linq

Comment: Please show how to "create a childsID property" with real compilable C# code. Please also show how "you can easily do the job with linq".